# Why encoder part of Autoencoder can work without fitting?

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

Sample code from https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

```
import keras
from keras import layers

# This is our input image
input_img = keras.Input(shape=(784,))
# "encoded" is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = layers.Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
# "decoded" is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# This model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)

# This model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = keras.Model(input_img, encoded)

# This is our encoded (32-dimensional) input
encoded_input = keras.Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
# Retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# Create the decoder model
decoder = keras.Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
...

# Encode and decode some digits
# Note that we take them from the *test* set
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
```

In the example, only model `autoencoder` had been compiled and fitted, `encoder` is not.

I am so confused, why encoder can predict new data directly without any compiling and fitting?

Answer (score 0):

`encoder` is a sub-model inside `autoencoder` (specifically, the part between `input_img` and `encoded`), it's not a separate model: you're just referring to a part of `autoencoder` with an explicit name.

When you train `autoencoder`, you're training both the encoder and decoder parts simultaneously. After training, `encoder` refers to the *trained* sub-model, that you can then use for inference.

Comment: So, if i want to get embeddings from autoencoder's encoder part, i need extract them by pre-trained autoencoder model, rather than encoder in the above sample, right?

Comment: No, you do exactly as in the example. `encoder` **is** the autoencoder's encoder part (as in, they are exactly the same object).